# How to get Ubuntu in boot menu back?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, multi-boot

I had installed Ubuntu 8.10 on my old laptop but when I intalled Win XP2, I lost it from the boot menu. Now when I power on the laptop, it loads windows right away.

How do I get Ubuntu back on boot menu?

Comment: Use a ubuntu CD to reinstall grub.

Comment: How do you just reinstall only the grub?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it once. I can't remember the source of the info, but here's my notes:

> **Graphical Method – Boot Repair**
>
> Boot Repair is a graphical tool that can repair GRUB2 with a single click. This is the ideal solution to boot problems for most users. If you have the media you installed Ubuntu from, insert it into your computer and restart.
>
> If you don’t, download a Ubuntu live CD and burn it to a disc or install it on a USB flash drive. You can also download a dedicated Boot Repair live CD. After booting into the live Ubuntu environment, open a terminal from the Dash and run the following commands to install Boot Repair:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
> boot-repair
> ```